# Can you sftp and scp into windows openssh with bash set as the default shell?

Tags: windows, bash, openssh, sftp, scp

When the default ssh shell is set to powershell:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

I can ssh,scp and sftp into the windows machine without problem.

When the default ssh shell is set to bash (WSL2):

```
 New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

I can only ssh into the windows machine, scp & sftp hang.

Using the -vvv switch gives verbose output indicating that authentication is ok, the process hangs right at the end, here's the tail:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f Downloads/test.jpg
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
```

Any ideas for how to get scp & sftp to play nice with bash?

Answer (score 1):

Full setup for msys2:

1. Create a wrapper `bashFromSsh.bat`, which can be placed anywhere. This wrapper will be set as the default shell in the registry (this is needed because we need to invoke the shell with arguments, which isn't possible from the registry key itself):

```
@echo off
C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -defterm -no-start -msys %*
```

2. Set the default shell from an admin powershell:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\path\to\bashFromSsh.bat" -PropertyType String -Force
```

3. In `C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config`, replace as follows:

```
#Subsystem      sftp    sftp-server.exe
Subsystem       sftp    /c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/sftp-server.exe
```

This is needed so that bash can find sftp-server.exe.

4. Restart the sshd service.

And that's it: ssh works (with or without arguments), so does scp and sftp.

This can probably be adapted to wsl/wsl2 by replacing `/c` by `/mnt/c`.